# Is there any method to convert multi class nominal categorical column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which one feature as multi class categorical column.
I have to convert this column into numerical column.
As it is Nominal i cannot use label encoder, and if i use dummies extra 1599 columns will be added.
shape of train_df is 1599 rows.

```
train_df['Item_Identifier'].value_counts()

FDW13    10
FDG33    10
FDV38     9
FDW26     9
NCQ06     9
FDQ40     9
FDU12     9
FDD38     9
FDG09     9
FDO19     9
FDT07     9
FDX20     9
FDX31     9
NCL31     9
FDF52     9
...
```

Comment: Could you edit your question with more details on what you want to achieve, don't write everything in the title, and also include the expected output, thanks

Comment: What would you like to do with this variable? Make a plot, fit a model ... ?